# A subset $E$ of $\Bbb R^k$ is compact if and only if it is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I know that the definition says that the subset needs to be bounded too, but if a subset is closed, then we get bounded for free too right? Sorry for bad English, my first language is Dutch.

Comment: No, consider all of $\mathbb{R}^k$. This is closed since it contains all its limit points, but not bounded.

Comment: ok got it, how can i change my question such that people dont flag me , should i delete it altogether? thanks guys!

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ it would not be sufficient to be close, due to [Heine Borel Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)

Comment: You should delete it. Note that closed and bounded is sufficient in $\mathbb R^n$ because it is complete. There are many engineers and physicists that think that closed and bounded is equivalent to compactness in general but it is not.

Comment: "but if a subset is closed, then we get bounded for free too right? "  No!  I don't know why you keep thinking this. If we got bounded for free we would specify closed *AND* bounded.....  But just to make it completely clear:  Closed sets do *not* need to be bounded.

Answer (score 1):

No, it needs to be bounded also.

For simplicity let’s suppose we’re in $\mathbb{R}$  equipped with the standard metric and consider $\mathbb{R}$ (as a subset of it’s self). Then $\mathbb{R}$ is closed (trivially), but the sequence $x_n=n$ can’t have a convergent subsequence since for any infinite sequence in the natural numbers $(n_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $n_k < n_{k+1}$, we have  $x_{n_k} \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

It's a theorem, the Heine-Borel theorem, that a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is compact if and only if closed *and* bounded.

Closed does not imply bounded.  Consider $\Bbb R^k\setminus B(0,1)$.

Comment: whats B in B(0,1) , is that the domain?

Comment: The open ball of radius $1$ centered at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

your "Rk" is $\mathbb{R}^k$? Conterexample: Let $E:= \mathbb{R}^k$. It is closed in $\mathbb{R}^k$. On the other hand $E$ is covered by open discs $D_n(0)$ around $0$ with radius $n \in \mathbb{N}$: $E= \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B_n(0)$. But you cannot find finite number of the discs $D_{n_1},... D_{n_l}$ such that their union cover $E$. This contradicts the general definition of compactness: Every open cover of a compact set has a finite subcover. A contradiction to your claim